# Will Android tablets have issues if they are always on?

Tags: tablet, screen

I plan on using an Android tablet in an always-on scenario (a fancy self-coded alarm clock, but this would apply to numerous uses).  Is there any problems with keeping an Android tablet on and charging all the time?  Is this likely to cause screen issues?

Comment: There's a reason for the tablet to go asleep, as is with most Android devices, it would be bad to keep the screen on all the time as that would drain the battery! In terms of screen issues, you're referring to screen-burn in, like the old days of MS-DOS command line gets burned into the CRT? Do not think this would happen here in this case, allow Android to manage the battery by shutting off the screen where applicable, do not override it as that is a bad thing to do... :)

Comment: @t0mm13b in terms off battery, just read the question again: *charging all the time*, i.e. permanently connected to a power source. I doubt that drains the battery :D And there's a setting to keep the screen on in those cases, yes...

Comment: @Izzy oh hai! Yeah, I have said that and emphasized why the devices sleep, i.e. to conserve battery, and plugging it in permanently would reduce battery life considerably, like laptops, if it has 3hr battery life, and plug it in constantly to mains, then it will have a short life, i.e. possibly 2hrs or worse, this laptop here suffered! :) And yes, there's a screen keep on option when plugged in within Developers options (different in ICS/JB and GB) *Stay Awake*.... :)

Comment: Well, *that's* a different (and valid) point: Once used like that for a year it might be no fun without A/C thereafter. But if there are no plans to disconnect it anyhow, this shouldn't become an issue ;)

Comment: Yep, battery deterioration is one that I did consider but my  intent is that it would be permanently connected, much like any other alarm clock.

Answer (score 3):

OLED screen are very bad for burn in and colour leaking (even worse that plasma screens in alot of cases) [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_burn-in](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_burn-in)
and so leaving them on the same screen for some time would not be a good idea
You might also find the general life of the device shortened because of the hardware being used all the time, but unless you are putting the device under stress im sure it would be fine.
The battery would likely weaken over time as well due to the constant charging

Comment: What screens are they that suffer from it? Did not think it would. Also the OP seems to have implied, developing their own app *a fancy self-coded alarm clock*)...

Comment: Yes sorry should have included this, OLED screen are very bad for burn in and colour leaking (even worse that plasma screens in alot of cases) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_burn-in

Comment: Oh... :) suggest you should put that in :)